# 3 character country codes using google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way I can get the 3 char country code in Google maps's Reverse Geocoding?

The below query returns the 2 char country code (ISO 3166-1 encoding). But I need to have the 3 char country code.
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookup table based on javascript multi dimensional array and using [**jquery**](http://jquery.com/)

```
var countries = [
{"two" : "AF","three" : "AFG" },
{"two" : "AL","three" : "ALB" },
{"two" : "DZ","three" : "DZA" },
{"two" : "AS","three" : "ASM" },
{"two" : "AD","three" : "AND" },
{"two" : "AO","three" : "AGO" },
{"two" : "AI","three" : "AIA" },
{"two" : "AQ","three" : "ATA" },
{"two" : "AG","three" : "ATG" },
{"two" : "AR","three" : "ARG" },
{"two" : "AM","three" : "ARM" },
{"two" : "AW","three" : "ABW" }
];//etc

var getKeyByParameter = function(obj, parameter) {
var returnVal = "";

$.each(obj, function(key, info) {
    if (info.two == parameter) {
       returnVal = info.three;
        return false; 
    };   
});

return returnVal;       

}

console.log(getKeyByParameter(countries, 'AG'));
```

Returns ATG

Comment: thanks David, but I do not want to do the mapping in my code. The reason is that I do not want to maintain this mapping.

Comment: You require Map for Google's geocoding service.